# How to update the title/text of Hyperlink present in Word document using Open XML SDK in C#

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Is there any way to update the text/title of the existing hyperlink present in the word document using Open XML SDK in C#?

I am able to update the address/link of hyperlink present in the word document using below Code:

```
    public static Stream GetAndUpdateAllHyperLinksInWordDocumentUsingOpenXMLSDKWithStream(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            //Hyperlink hLink = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Hyperlink>().FirstOrDefault();
            var hLinks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Hyperlink>();

            Console.WriteLine(hLinks.Count());

            foreach (var hLink in hLinks)
            {

                if (hLink != null)
                {
                    // get hyperlink's relation Id (where path stores)
                    string relationId = hLink.Id;
                    if (relationId != string.Empty)
                    {
                        // get current relation
                        var hr = mainPart.HyperlinkRelationships.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == relationId);
                        if (hr == null) continue;
                        var linkUrl = hr.Uri.ToString();

                        mainPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(hr);
                        string linkToReplace = string.Empty;

                        try
                        {
                            //Link to Replace in the word document.
                            linkToReplace = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

                            mainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new System.Uri(linkToReplace, System.UriKind.Absolute), true, relationId);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred while adding target url, Error Message: " + exc.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            doc.Close();

            return stream;
            // return updated document stream
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred: " + exc.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have searched a lot everywhere on the internet but couldn't find a way to update the title of the hyperlink in word document using Open XML SDK in C#.

Can anybody please suggest how to achieve the same?

Thanks in Advance.